# How to start an keyframe animation automatically

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am making my first experiences with html css today. I have created an animation here that is triggered on hover. Now I want the animation to be triggered by itself after about 5 seconds without hover. How do I have to proceed here to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Shake</title>
    <style>

    .shake:hover {
      animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }

    @keyframes shake {
      10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
      }
  
      20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
      }

      30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
      }

      40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(7px, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="shake">Shake</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add a different animation to the normal element without hover, and make that one just have a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `:hover` pseudo class from the css and add `animation-delay` property for 5s (or whatever delay you want).

```css
 .shake {
      animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      perspective: 1000px;
      animation-delay: 5s
    }

    @keyframes shake {
      10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-2px, 0, 0);
      }
  
      20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
      }

      30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-8px, 0, 0);
      }

      40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(7px, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Shake</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="shake">Shake</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `animation-delay` property. This will execute the animation after 5 seconds after the page element is displayed.

```css
.shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```